# IFrame Double Click Ad server with Rich Media

Tags: iframe, ads, double-click, advertisement-server

I am using double click ad server to manage ads on my website.
I am using DART IFrame tags for faster rendering of the site plus other purposes.

I want to implement rich media using the IFrame tags. I followed the DFP tutoral (https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/117857) but still no good result.

I need a step by step tutorial to do so.

I am using the below tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ord = window.ord || Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e16);
  document.write('<iframe    src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N7229/adi/new;sz=728x90;ord=' + ord + '?" width="728"     height="90" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N7229/jump/new;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?">
<img src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/N7229/ad/new;sz=728x90;ord=[timestamp]?" width="728" height="90" />
</a>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DFP Premium or DFP Samll business.

The ad-tag you've provided is a regular iFrame DFP Tag - however, to serve Rich Media you will typically use a vendor who will provide you with their tags. You will typically traffic the rich media ad in DFP and serve it out onto your site using a tag similar to the one you pasted.

The one issues with iframes and rich media is that you may require some server-side 'stub' files to be hosted from each of the rich media vendors you use to build/serve your rich media adverts. These are required only if your planning to serve an 'expanding' or 'floating' ad format so they can expand/bust out of the iframe.

Not sure if your question is how to serve Rich Media ads or if your trying to build a rich media ad to serve out of your DFP instance.

Doubleclick have their own rich media product that you can use to build rich media creative - this will allow you to serve the creative from your instance of DFP. Otherwise you can use other vendors on the market - mediamind, flashtalking, pointroll, etc, etc. These guys will provide you with a JavaScript tag that you will then traffic into your DFP instance to serve the creative. Whatever vendor you use - make it clear from the start that your planning to serve the final creative via an iframe tag on your side...

Hope that helps...